# Fine white fuzzy layer all over Ipomoea. What can it be?

Tags: diseases, leaves

[image][image][image]I have noticed a fading on my Ipomoea leaves and a fine white fuzz around the leaves too.

Can anyone help me identify the problem? They grow on may balcony, Have plenty of sunshine and have not been fertilised.

Comment: A picture of the situation would be very helpful for identification of the problem.

Comment: @benn here are some pictures. Thank you

Comment: This is a spider mite infection.

Comment: Oh dear. will I be able to save the plant by hosing it down or shall I uproot it? @benn?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am personally myself not a champ in curing spider mites infections. But you might want to search this site or google, to find ways to treat this infection. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a spider mite infection. You should treat it with an acaricide (not insecticide). They should have special stuff for the mites at your local garden supply store.

Answer (score 0):

Used a combination of oil:dish soap , 3:1, Sprayed the plant every alternate day for 10 days and it is now Thriving! :) FYI @daria @ben